# Wrong output when using stl map application in arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, vector

Here is my code, I am using an array instead of a map to check if the element is repeated or not, and then I'm adding the corresponding values of indexes at which the element is present, in the vector , but every time it is returning 0.

```
class Solution{
    public:
    //Function to return the position of the first repeating element.
    int firstRepeated(int arr[], int n) {
        //code here
    vector<int> v(n,0);
    int a[1000001]={-1};
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[arr[i]]==-1)
            a[arr[i]]=i+1;
            v[i]=a[arr[i]];
    }
    int min=INT_MAX;
    for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(min>v[i]  && v[i]!=i+1)
        min=v[i];
    }
    if(min!=INT_MAX)
    return min;
    return -1;
    }
};
```

Assistance will be appreciated☺

Comment: And when you used your debugger to execute the above program, one line at a time, what did you see?

Comment: `int a[1000001]={-1}` initializes the first element to -1 and the rest to 0. Also why does your question title mention maps when you don't use them?

Comment: The indentation of your first `if` suggests Python-style code grouping, which C++ will not honor.  That if-statement ends at the first `;`

Comment: That comment just gave me a flashback to the two-dimensional thinking dialogue at the end of Wrath of Khan. Solution to the problem is just as simple.

Comment: `int a[1000001]={-1};` -- This would instantly blow out the stack memory using the default Visual C++ settings.  Why do you want to declare an array this size anyway?  Your desire to use an array just made the code not being able to compile -- and if it compiled, a stack overflow error will occur.  Choose your containers wisely -- making the choice of an array, or at least what you plan to use it for, is the wrong choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the first things to note is your if statement syntax. In c++ if it is more than 1 line long you must encapsulate it with {}.
So for this section:

```
if(a[arr[i]]==-1)
    a[arr[i]]=i+1;
    v[i]=a[arr[i]];
```

It is always going to execute v[i] regardless of what the if evaluates to.
So

```
if(some condition){
   //lines of code
   //another line of code
}
```

Second the logic here doesn't make sense.

```
if(a[arr[i]]==-1)
```

You can't guarantee which numbers are in arr[]. What if arr[i] = 1million, then a[1million] doesn't exist since it is only 1000001 long.

Why pick a to be 1000001? It doesn't have any relevance to the size of arr[] or int n.
Keep your sizes consistent.

On a more general sense this comes down to what information you are expecting in arr[]. If the array of numbers here is sorted or unsorted this affects the solution greatly. If it is sorted, you only need to loop through and check the next value:

```
if(arr[i] == arr[i+1]){
//store value of i for earliest instance of repeat
}
```

If it isn't sorted then you have to either sort it first or check the whole array for other instances of repeating using something like a nested loop.